# R: number rows that match >= other row within group

Tags: r, match, data.table

Is it possible to match two tables against each other, where one variable >= the other one, but within a group?

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(rep(1,6),rep(2,4)), 
                 IDSEQ=c(seq(1,6),seq(1,4)), 
                 TAG = c(0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0))
```

Here's a brief example of what the table looks like:

```
ID  IDSEQ TAG
1   1     0
1   2     0
1   3     1
1   4     0
1   5     1
1   6     0
2   1     0
2   2     1
2   3     0
2   4     0
```

I've created a little lookup (needs to be done using min as several TAG's might occure within each ID group):

```
df2 <- df[which(df$TAG == 1), ]

library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df2)
DT <- DT[, list(IDSEQ=min(IDSEQ)), by=ID]

ID  IDSEQ
1   3
2   2
```

I was thinking of numbering the rows by ID where `df$ID == DT$ID` and `df$IDSEQ >= DT$IDSEQ`, but there might be other ways to solve this.

The result should look like this.

```
ID  IDSEQ TAG   CASES
1   1     0     0
1   2     0     0
1   3     1     1
1   4     0     2
1   5     1     3
1   6     0     4
2   1     0     0
2   2     1     1
2   3     0     2
2   4     0     3
```

I think this might be done with `data.table`, but I have only used simple statements so far.

Comment: In your second code block, you show min(IDSEQ) as 3 and 2, which is not consistent with your example in the first code block.

Comment: @Frank the first time TAG is 1 for ID 1 is at IDSEQ 3 and the first time TAG is 1 for ID2 is IDSEQ 2, so the example is correct

Comment: yes sorry, forgotten one step!

Comment: Ok, should now be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think merging data.tables might be useful here. Something like...

```
DT0 <- data.table(df)
setkey(DT0,ID) # the first data.table in a merge must be keyed

DT0[DT,IDSEQ >= i.IDSEQ] # this labels whether each row satisfies the condition
```

I'm not sure where the prefix `i.` is documented, but it refers to the column from the second table in the `X[Y,...]` join.

---

I'm still trying to find an elegant way to number the rows within groups. This is one clumsy approach:

```
DT0[,CASES:=0L]
DT0[DT0[DT,.I[IDSEQ >= i.IDSEQ]]$V1,CASES:=1:.N,by=ID]
```

which gives

```
    ID IDSEQ TAG CASES
 1:  1     1   0     0
 2:  1     2   0     0
 3:  1     3   1     1
 4:  1     4   0     2
 5:  1     5   1     3
 6:  1     6   0     4
 7:  2     1   0     0
 8:  2     2   1     1
 9:  2     3   0     2
10:  2     4   0     3
```

This uses the special variables `.I` and `.N`, which are documented in `help('data.table')`.