# R data.table update errors

Tags: r, data.table

Some more problems I'm having with old `data.table` code related to this:
[R: number rows that match >= other row within group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22416211/r-number-rows-that-match-other-row-within-group)

The data looks like this, with a different ID for each person, IDSEQ is the sequence of each admission for this person and TAG for diabetes medication (TAG=1 hypoglycaemic agent and TAG=2 insulin).

```
   ID IDSEQ TAG
1   1     1   0
2   1     2   0
3   1     3   0
4   1     4   0
5   1     5   0
6   1     6   0
7   1     7   0
8   1     8   1
9   1     9   0
10  1    10   0
11  2     1   0
12  2     2   0
13  2     3   0
14  2     4   1
15  2     5   0
16  2     6   0
17  2     7   0
18  2     8   2
19  2     9   0
20  2    10   0

# recreate this data with
df <- data.frame(ID=c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10)),
                 IDSEQ=c(1:10,1:10),
                 TAG=c(rep(0,7),1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0))
```

Exercise: Create two new index sequence variables, COND1 using TAG=1 as the index record, and COND2 using TAG=2 as the index record. Write your syntax so that only record in a block prior to the index records in a block prior to the index record are numbered with a '0'.

a) TAG=1 (seems to still work)

```
DT <- data.table(df)
setkey(DT, ID)

# counter for condition 1
tmp <- df[which(df$TAG == 1),1:2]
DT1 <- data.table(tmp)
DT1 <- DT1[, list(IDSEQ=min(IDSEQ)), by=ID]

DT[, COND1:=0L]
DT[DT[DT1,.I[IDSEQ >= i.IDSEQ]],COND1:=1:.N,by=ID]
# previously 
# DT[DT[DT1,.I[IDSEQ >= i.IDSEQ]]$V1,COND1:=1:.N,by=ID]
```

a) TAG=2 does not result in the correct result anymore, it is not linked on both ID and IDSEQ.

```
tmp <- df[which(df$TAG == 2),1:2]
DT1 <- data.table(tmp)
DT1 <- DT1[, list(IDSEQ=min(IDSEQ)), by=ID]

DT[, COND2:=0L]
DT[DT[DT1,.I[IDSEQ >= i.IDSEQ]],COND2:=1:.N,by=ID]

# previously worked with
# DT[DT[DT1,.I[IDSEQ >= i.IDSEQ]]$V1,COND2:=1:.N,by=ID]
```

The overall result should look like this

```
   ID IDSEQ TAG COND1 COND2
1   1     1   0     0     0
2   1     2   0     0     0
3   1     3   0     0     0
4   1     4   0     0     0
5   1     5   0     0     0
6   1     6   0     0     0
7   1     7   0     0     0
8   1     8   1     1     0
9   1     9   0     2     0
10  1    10   0     3     0
11  2     1   0     0     0
12  2     2   0     0     0
13  2     3   0     0     0
14  2     4   1     1     0
15  2     5   0     2     0
16  2     6   0     3     0
17  2     7   0     4     0
18  2     8   2     5     1
19  2     9   0     6     2
20  2    10   0     7     3

# recreate this data with
  data.frame(ID=c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10)),
             IDSEQ=c(1:10,1:10),
             TAG=c(rep(0,7),1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0),
             COND1=c(rep(0,7),1,2,3,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
             COND2=c(rep(0,17),1,2,3))
```

`data.table` Version 1.9.4, R version 3.1.1

Comment: it's the data.frame mentioned in the linked post

Comment: added, but don't understand what you mean by 'be sure to work on your data.frame'

Comment: Remove the `$V1` part as in `DT0[DT0[DT,.I[IDSEQ >= i.IDSEQ]],CASES:=1:.N,by=ID]`. In general, when you trying to debug some code, you should do it in steps from inside out. If you''d run just `DT0[DT,.I[IDSEQ >= i.IDSEQ]]` you would notice that this returns an atomic vecotor rather a `data.table`, thus `$` certainly won't work

Comment: I have done this, but the overall solution of the exercise changes (which is weird)

Comment: Perhaps it's an order problem - I will start again

Comment: It's not weird considering `data.table` is a constantly developing package. It is constantly changes its behaviour depending on users requests/bug fixes and etc. This has its pros an cons. I would suggest following the updates for each new version in [this link](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table). If you want to stick to a certain behavior, just don't update to a newer version.

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming question.  You report some "weirdness", but what is your question?

Comment: I think you now need to add `by=.EACHI` (or remove the `$V1`), since the so-called by-without-by that used to be automatic upon joins has been taken out. http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/changing-data-table-by-without-by-syntax-to-require-a-quot-by-quot-td4664770.html

Comment: Basically the code will run, but it will now join on the wrong column.

Comment: Could you explain to us clearly in words what your actual task is? Please edit your post, don't explain under comments.

Comment: Houw about `setDT(df)[, COND1 := c(rep(0L, which(TAG == 1L) - 1L), seq_len(.N - which(TAG == 1L) + 1L)), ID]` first condition?

Comment: Very sleek, that works very well - even when applying to 1.5 million records.

Comment: The result is correct, but I get a message `Error in rep(0L, which(TAG == 1L) - 1L) : invalid 'times' argument` when applying to the massive dataset.

Comment: Yes, it happens when you don't have a single `1` in a certain `ID`.

Comment: How about `setDT(df)[, COND1 :=  if(length(which(TAG == 1L)) > 0) c(rep(0L, which(TAG == 1L) - 1L), seq_len(.N - which(TAG == 1L) + 1L)), ID]` and 
`df[, COND2 :=  if(length(which(TAG == 2L)) > 0) c(rep(0L, which(TAG == 2L) - 1L), seq_len(.N - which(TAG == 2L) + 1L)), ID]`

Comment: it's not quite the same as the previous code, but it's only visible about 100 lines of code later when the summary stats are called

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Didn't it work for you?

Comment: It works on the small example, but the underlying coding result is different to the previously used code - so no, it does not work as expected on the very large dataset. I'm trying to get help from someone with access to the data now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corrected last line of your example:

```
DT[DT[DT1, .I[IDSEQ >= i.IDSEQ], by=.EACHI]$V1, COND2:=1:.N, by=ID]
```

Alternatively, you could also alter the default behavior, although I wouldn't recommend it due to compatibility issues.

```
options(datatable.old.bywithoutby=TRUE)
```

Some background information:

The selection criteria for `TAG==2` results in

```
DT[DT1,.I[IDSEQ >= i.IDSEQ]]
[1]  8  9 10
```

which are the correct indices (line number) for `ID==2` after the subset/join.

You would experience the same problem/result if there would be e.g. an `ID==0` without any `TAG==1`.

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(0, rep(1,10),rep(2,10)),
             IDSEQ=c(1, 1:10,1:10),
             TAG=c(0, rep(0,7),1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0))

DT <- data.table(df)
setkey(DT, ID)

# counter for condition 1
tmp <- df[which(df$TAG == 1),1:2]
DT1 <- data.table(tmp)
DT1 <- DT1[, list(IDSEQ=min(IDSEQ)), by=ID]

DT[, COND1:=0L]
DT[DT[DT1, .I[IDSEQ >= i.IDSEQ]], COND1:=1:.N, by=ID]

DT[c(1,2, 7:10),]
   ID IDSEQ TAG COND1
1:  0     1   0     0
2:  1     1   0     0
3:  1     6   0     0
4:  1     7   0     1
5:  1     8   1     2
6:  1     9   0     3
```

data.table handles this situation (`by-without-by`) differently since version 1.9.4. When loading data.table it states

```
> library(data.table)
data.table 1.9.4  For help type: ?data.table
*** NB: by=.EACHI is now explicit. See README to restore previous behaviour.
```

Therefore you need to explicitly tell that you want to get your results `j` (the second part of the statement) not only for the current subset (defined in the first part), but grouped by every key variable.

More information can be found in the data.table FAQ 1.13 and 1.14 on page 5 and 6.

Comment: Thanks, you are a life saver! That does exactly the same as before!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using `data.table`:

```
dt[, `:=`(count1 = cumsum(cumsum(TAG == 1L)), 
          count2 = cumsum(cumsum(TAG == 2L))
         ), by=ID]
#     ID IDSEQ TAG count1 count2
#  1:  1     1   0      0      0
#  2:  1     2   0      0      0
#  3:  1     3   0      0      0
#  4:  1     4   0      0      0
#  5:  1     5   0      0      0
#  6:  1     6   0      0      0
#  7:  1     7   0      0      0
#  8:  1     8   1      1      0
#  9:  1     9   0      2      0
# 10:  1    10   0      3      0
# 11:  2     1   0      0      0
# 12:  2     2   0      0      0
# 13:  2     3   0      0      0
# 14:  2     4   1      1      0
# 15:  2     5   0      2      0
# 16:  2     6   0      3      0
# 17:  2     7   0      4      0
# 18:  2     8   2      5      1
# 19:  2     9   0      6      2
# 20:  2    10   0      7      3
```

Comment: This is also a valid solution for this question, however, it would be more difficult for the students to grab this concept.